# How to upload a file in to Google Drive from Android App(GoogleDrive API integration)

Tags: android, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I would like to upload file into google drive from `android` app.I got the example from [this](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) link for uploading a photo into Google Drive from camera.I didn't get any better solution for uploading a file(.txt,.pdf,.doc).so anyone please suggest a needful information to me.

Answer (score 0):

The [android-demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) is a more complete reference application that demonstrates file creation, etc.

Comment: `com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
    com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID`
what value we have to set in these two fields.
and also it will be helpful if upload a file into `GoogleDrive` from device